# How does Apache handle port forwarding?

Tags: apache-2.2, port, redirection

I setup a localhost portforwarding configuration in the coLinux .conf
file, forwarding port 8090 to port 80 in the VM.

When http://localhost:8090 is entered in the browser, I get the
correct response from nginx, but  with Apache the response get the
error /htdocs not found in the log.

However if I do a local port forwarding from 8090 to port 80 via SSH
Apache responds fine.

Is there something about the way Apache handles the port redirection
that causes it to fail?

PS, For those unfamiliar with coLinux it allows localhost connections to get to the VM by forwarding localhost ports on the Windows host to ports on the VM, as the 10.x.x.x IP it not accessible from the Windows host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same domain name for each request?  Apache is probably configured to serve up the site based on the DNS name you use, as well as the port.  So if you request `http://localhost` on one machine, and `http://www.foo.com` on another, you're going to get drastically different results.